# Box enterprise rename event

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am developing an app for Box enterprise and I found out that rename events come with the new name but no the old one, for example

```
{
  "source": {
    "item_type": "file",
    "item_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "item_name": "secret file 2.txt",
    "parent": {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "All Files",
      "id": "0"
    }
  },
  "created_by": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "Ronan",
    "login": "r@agora.co"
  },
  "created_at": "2016-06-20T09:22:55-07:00",
  "event_id": "a64748af-1693-4651-af41-5eed55414677",
  "event_type": "RENAME",
  "ip_address": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
  "type": "event",
  "session_id": null,
  "additional_details": {
    "shared_link_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "version_id": "67450313377"
  }
}
```

How can I see the previous name of the file as well?

Comment: I thought the [File Versions](https://docs.box.com/reference#view-versions-of-a-file) API might offer a solution, but renaming a file (via the web app) doesn't appear to result in a new version.

Comment: Is your app performing the rename operation?

Comment: No, the rename operation occurs in Box. I just get the event list from the API and through webhook notifications

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?